# Finding $a_{-n}$ where $\cot (\pi z)=\sum_{n=-\infty } ^\infty a_nz^n$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

The following is problem 5.11.2 of *Berkeley Problems in Mathematics*.

> Let $\cot (\pi z)=\sum_{-\infty} ^\infty a_nz^n$ be the Laurent expansion for $\cot (\pi z)$ on the annulus $1<\vert z \vert <2$. Compute the $a_n$ for $n<0$.

Now $a_{-1}$ is simply the residue of $\cot(\pi z)$ at $z=0$. So $a_{-1}=\frac {\cos (\pi 0)}{\pi \cos (\pi 0)}=\frac{1}{\pi }.$

However, in the solution to the problem, they have 
$$a_{-1}=\text{Res}(\cot \pi z,-1)+\text{Res}(\cot \pi z,0)+\text{Res}(\cot \pi z,1)=\frac{3}{\pi }$$

Why are they combining the residues for 3 distinct expansions and then adding them together to find $a_{-1}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your statement that $a_{-1}$ is the residue at $0$ would have been correct if you were looking for the Laurent series on $0 < |z| < 1$.

In general, if you are working on the annulus $r < |z-c| < R$, then
$$
a_n = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\gamma} \frac{f(\zeta)}{(\zeta-c)^{n+1}} \,d\zeta
$$
where $\gamma$ is a simple closed curve in the annulus, for example $|z-c|=\rho$ for some $r < \rho < R$. In your particular case, when you evaluate the integral, the residues at $z=0$ and $z=\pm 1$ are all relevant.